# Error with registration of service worker in angular project

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-service-worker

I have a problem with the registration of service worker in an **Angular** project.
When I launch the project, in the DevTools of Chrome's Console appear these errors:

1. Uncaught (in promise) DOMException;
2. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a
   ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when
   fetching the script;
3. ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Failed to register
   a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when
   fetching the script.

> TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response
>   code (404) was received when fetching the script.

How can I solve?

Comment: Not able to find the script file of service worker, can you please replicate some of your code, how you are registering the service worker ?

Comment: What parts of code should I post? Which project's file?

Comment: Did you try to add it with angular cli command https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#adding-a-service-worker-to-your-project


ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*

Comment: Yes, I did it!!

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Can use reproduce the same on https://stackblitz.com or try to host on github, so i can review it ?